# AngularJS - please explain the line

Tags: angularjs

What exactly does the "inject" line do?:

```
function PhotoGalleryCtrl($route, $xhr) {
}

PhotoGalleryCtrl.$inject = ['$route', '$xhr'];
```

Are $route and $xhr predefined somewhere? Where to read about them?

Who said that the PhotoGalleryCtrl function has the .$inject method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `$route` and `$xhr` are native AngularJS services, the latter has been replaced by `$http` in the most recent versions of AngularJS. They are part of the `ng` module.

You can read about them here

- [ng.$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route)
- [ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

`$inject` tells angular to make available those services to the controller `PhotoGalleryCtrl`

Dependency injection and modules are core features of Angular. They both minimize global state and allow for better unit testing, you can read more about them here

- [Modules](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)
- [Dependency Injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)